# 4 tables insert - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, multi-table-inheritance

[image: Relationship]

I want to insert by selecting `@DistName` and `@ProvName` from `district` and `province`

```
INSERT INTO
    users
VALUES
(
    '@UserName',
    '@email',
    '@Pass',
    '@Status',
    '@phoneNo',
    '@VillName',
    '@DistName',
    '@ProvName'
);
```

Comment: Nice job illustrating the DDL of your relations.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `SELECT` statement to get the fields from other tables like below.

```
INSERT INTO
  users
VALUES
(
  '@UserName',
  '@email',
  '@Pass',
  '@Status',
  '@phoneNo',
  '@VillName',
  (SELECT '@DistName' FROM TABLE district WHERE distID=1),
  (SELECT '@ProvName' FROM TABLE province WHERE ProvID=1)
);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> *Note*:  Just count the fields' number in the table `users` and your trying to insert values number...

IMHO, strange relationships. But how I've understood => U need to get `VilllD` for inserting to `users` from three tables => `village` & `district` & `province`. It should look like:

```
INSERT INTO
 users
VALUES
(
 '@UserName',
 '@email',
 '@Pass',
 '@Status',
 '@phoneNo',
 (SELECT v.VilllD FROM village AS v 
                    INNER JOIN district AS d
                      ON v.DistID = d.DistID
                    INNER JOIN province AS p
                      ON p.ProvId = d.ProvId
                    WHERE v.VillName = @Villname AND
                          d.DistName = @DistName AND
                          p.ProvName = @ProvName )
);
```